# Query to fetch list of user privileges on a given table doesn't output all users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning `Postgres`. Now, I'm checking things like user permissions. After creating the role `Business` I added to table `employee` the following `GRANT`:

`GRANT SELECT ("fname", "minit", "lname", "bdate", "address", "dno") on employee TO business;`

This is the table:

```
  fname   | minit |  lname  |    ssn    |   bdate    |         address         | sex |  salary  | super_ssn | dno 
----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-----+----------+-----------+-----
 James    | E     | Borg    | 888665555 | 1937-11-10 | 450 Stone, Houston TX   | M   | 55000.00 |           |   1
 John     | B     | Smith   | 123456789 | 1965-01-09 | 731 Fondren, Houston TX | M   | 30000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Franklin | T     | Wong    | 333445555 | 1955-12-08 | 638 Voss, Houston TX    | M   | 40000.00 | 888665555 |   5
 Alicia   | J     | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 1968-01-19 | 3321 Castle, Spring TX  | F   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
 Jennifer | S     | Wallace | 987654321 | 1941-06-20 | 291 Berry, Bellaire TX  | F   | 43000.00 | 888665555 |   4
 Ramesh   | K     | Narayan | 666884444 | 1962-09-15 | 975 Fire Oak, Humble TX | M   | 38000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Joyce    | A     | English | 453453453 | 1972-07-31 | 5631 Rice, Houston TX   | F   | 25000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Ahmad    | V     | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 1969-03-29 | 980 Dallas, Houston TX  | M   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
```

I've found a few threads here on StackOverflow with some examples, but these are not achieving what I'm looking for.

When I use

```
SELECT user, string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='employee'   
GROUP BY user;
```

I get the following:

```
 user  |                          privileges                           
-------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 Admin | INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER
```

The new role called `Business` doesn't show up. It works with `\z employee`, but that type of view is not what I'm looking for, I want a query.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks! In my question here I mentioned `\z employee.` What I'm looking for is _why_ in my query it isn't outputting the newly created user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the table in the result of your query because you have not granted any privileges on the table level, only on the column level.

You'd have to look in [`information_schema.role_column_grants`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-role-column-grants.html):

```
SELECT grantee,
       column_name,
       string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_column_grants 
WHERE table_name='employee'   
GROUP BY grantee, column_name;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a query, not to do a visual lookup. I actually had one the I shared here, but in my system it wasn't outputting it properly, just the admin.

Comment: Just use that table in your query.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should clarify the title of the question, that query in my system won't output the new user created.

Comment: I'll test your query though since it's slightly different from what I have.

Comment: My answer covers that. You don't see the table in the result of your query becauae you have not granted any privileges on the table level, only on the column level.